# How to mark location in Google MAP

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have got Geo locations. i am trying to mark this location into Google map. please suggest me the best method. I have all locations in array that i want to use in the Google map

```
        Array
        (
            [0] => 51.508742, -0.134583
        )
        Array
        (
            [0] => 38.410558, 17.314453
        )
```

Comment: Do a google on "Google Maps API".

Comment: Working perfect for me ... Please vote me so that i will be up !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

```
//var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(yourArrayName[0][0], yourArrayName[0][1]);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

It would probably be easier to set up your array to contain an array with latitudes and longitudes in different elements rather than one string as it seems you may have.

Comment: Done found !! Its good !